# How can I set validation rules on my entity fields and get errors if the data isn't valid

Tags: entities, 9

I have this entity which got the link field

This link is mandatory, has to be more than 3 chars and less than 255
Also it has to be a valid URL

```php
class Myentity extends ContentEntityBase implements BaseEntityInterface {

  use EntityChangedTrait;

  public static function baseFieldDefinitions( EntityTypeInterface $entity_type )
  {
    $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);

    $fields['link'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Url'))
      ->setDescription(t('The entity url.'))
      ->setSettings(
        [
          'default_value' => '',
          'min_length' => 3,
          'max_length' => 255,
          'text_processing' => 0,
        ]
      )->setRequired(true)
      ->addConstraint('Length', ['min' => 3, 'max' => 255]);

  }


}
```

And then somewhere in the application, I want to save that entity

```php
$data = ['link': 'X'];

$entity = Myentity::create($data);

$violationList = $entity->validate();

echo $violationList->count(); //Prints 0 ! although the length isn't good!
```

`setRequired(true)` guarantees me that the field `link` is mandatory

`addConstraint('Length', ['min' => 3, 'max' => 255])` Doesn't seem to work, As I didn't get any error while validating my data

So I've some questions about this code:

1. How do we set the validation rules for an entity, I saw two functions `addConstraint` and `setPropertyConstraints`. which one to use or there is another way ?
2. After validating data, and if `$violationList->count()` is positive, How do we get the rules that failed, I know `$violationList->getFieldNames()` returns the invalid field but not the rule that failed.
3. And last, what are the rules that Drupal 9 provides, are they the ones that are shipped with the Symfony Validator components as stated in Drupal's documentation OR there is a defined list.

Comment: The *string* entity field has only the *max_length* setting, and that works, as it's used from [`Node::baseFieldDefinitions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/function/Node%3A%3AbaseFieldDefinitions/9.3.x). There is no need to add a constraint for that, which is already added from [`StringItem::getConstraints`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21StringItem.php/function/StringItem%3A%3AgetConstraints/9.3.x).

Answer (score 2):

I use addConstraint in my custom entities and haven't had a problem. I see your field definition is for "name" but your data says "link", maybe that's why?

Here's a snippet for getting the errors:

```
    $violations = $entity->validate();
    $errors = [];
    foreach ($violations as $violation) {
      $property = $violation->getPropertyPath();
      $field = explode('.', $property)[0];
      $label = $entity->get($field)->getFieldDefinition()->getLabel();
      $errors[] = $label . ': ' . $violation->getMessage();
    }
```

There's a list of core constraints here:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor!symfony!validator!ConstraintValidator.php/class/uses/ConstraintValidator/9.3.x